AMC 10 Math Question About Formula For A Sequence...
Find the value of $ \frac{{1^2 + 1 \cdot 2 + 2^2}}{{1^3 \cdot 2^3}} + \frac{{2^2 + 2 \cdot 3 + 3^2}}{{2^3 \cdot 3^3}} + \cdots + \frac{{10^2 + 10 \cdot 11 + 11^2}}{{10^3 \cdot 11^3}} $
This is a problem that I found in a AMC 10 perp book that was given to me by my math teacher the week before school ended. I was going through it and I got stuck on this question. How do I do it?

Do you have any thoughts of your own on this question? Try looking at small cases to deduce a pattern.

Yes, I know that $\frac{1}{n(n-1} = \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n-1}$ but I am not sure how to apply this because in my case the numerator is not one and the stuff is cubed...

You had the right idea in your comment. You just needed to take the logic a few steps further.
For this problem, it really helps to be familiar with the kinds of problems asked on math contests. A problem that asks you to sum a series of smaller and smaller fractions is nearly always either a geometric series (or a simple variant of one) or a telescoping series. This is not a geometric series. Ergo, it is probably a telescoping series....
Let's actually try. The series is $\sum_{n=1}^{10} a_n$, where
$$a_n = \frac{n^2 + n(n+1) + (n+1)^2}{n^3(n+1)^3}.$$ Expanding the top gives
$$a_n = \frac{3n^2 + 3n + 1}{n^3(n+1)^3}.$$
We are already on the lookout for a telescoping series -- that is, to write $a_n = f(n+1) - f(n)$. The top  looks almost like a familiar $f(n+1)$; namely, $(n+1)^3$. So let's rewrite it:
$$a_n = \frac{(n+1)^3 - n^3}{n^3(n+1)^3}.$$
Now this is of the form $\frac{v-u}{uv} = \frac{1}{u} - \frac{1}{v}.$ That is also a good pattern to practice recognizing for contests.
So we have
$$a_n = \frac{1}{n^3} - \frac{1}{(n+1)^3}$$ and, what do you know, it turned out to be the expected telescoping series.

(Moderately) alternative approach to the answer of anon:
$$(r^2 + rs + s^2) \times (s-r) = s^3 - r^3.$$
Therefore, when $~(s-r) = 1,~$ you have that
$$(r^2 + rs + s^2) = s^3 - r^3.$$
So, each term in the series can be re-expressed as
$$\frac{s^3 - r^3}{r^3 ~s^3} = \frac{1}{r^3} - \frac{1}{s^3} = \frac{1}{r^3} - \frac{1}{(r+1)^3} .$$
